# I have a df with countries and states when I select a particular country I need to get the output as below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I NEED OUTPUT AS {'IN':[HYD,VJY,BANG]}

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'country':['INDIA','INDIA','INDIA','PAKISTAN','PAKISTAN'],                   
              'city':['HYD','BANG','VJW','HYD','ISLAMABAD']})
a = input("please select the country").upper()
if a=='INDIA':
    print(df[df['country'] == 'INDIA'])

else:
    print(df[df['country'] == 'PAKISTAN'])
```

output:
country  city
0   INDIA   HYD
1   INDIA  BANG
2   INDIA   VJW

I tried using to_dict(),to_json() but I'm not getting the desired output.
Thanks

Comment: You just have to do to_list in city like this: `{a: df[df['country'] == a]['city'].to_list()}`. Output will be: `{'INDIA': ['HYD', 'BANG', 'VJW']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same answer as @Shikhar Verma suggested.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['INDIA', 'INDIA', 'INDIA', 'PAKISTAN', 'PAKISTAN'],
                   'city': ['HYD', 'BANG', 'VJW', 'HYD', 'ISLAMABAD']})

a = input("please select the country").upper()

print({a: df[df['country'] == a]['city'].to_list()})
```

output:

```
{'INDIA': ['HYD', 'BANG', 'VJW']}
```